# Limit container restart time(or count) inside a pod (deployment)

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, containers, restart, policy

I have a problem with the container restart duration. For me 1 minute  between container restart time is acceptable but based on the container restart policy the wait time increases after each restart.

> After containers in a Pod exit, the kubelet restarts them with an
> exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s, …), that is capped at five
> minutes. Once a container has executed for 10 minutes without any
> problems, the kubelet resets the restart backoff timer for that
> container.

So the question is how to limit container restart count or decrease maximum time from 5 minutes to 1 minute in deployment?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to consider using [Progress Deadline Seconds](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#progress-deadline-seconds) to specify the number of seconds you want to wait for a Deployment before the system report it failed. This will need to specify greater number of seconds on [minReadySeconds](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#min-ready-seconds).